# Can we train a model to work as a square function

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to train a model to works as square function.
But I m not able to figure out on what type of dataset I should train the model on.

what I want is that after I trained the model and call the predict the result should be the square of the number which I pass to the predict

example:`print(model.predict([5])`
it should print `25`

Comment: Your function has a known closed form. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use [Regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification) as you are trying to predict a real valued output.
- You cannot use only linear features of the input as we KNOW that the output is a second degree function of the input. So, what we need is a [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression).
- This can be done in sklearn as [linear regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) with [polynomial features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html).
- You can specify the degree to be anything >=2 and let the model choose which features are the most expressive. You can check this by plotting the weights learned by the model ([coef_ in this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)). What you should typically expect to see if the training goes well is one big spike for the x^2 feature and almost close to 0 for all else.

So in essence, train a linear regression model with features being some/many higher order polynomial representations of the input and let the model learn the that the output is actually one of the provided features.

[Edit] : But if you do not want to pass the feature explicitly , then you can try training a neural network with binary representations of input , trying to predict the binary representations of the output. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) got your back.

Answer (score 0):

Classification says which class an item belongs to not which value to output ,you are saying to classify and predict a value which do not belong to any class.Use a neural network kind of predictor for this task which is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Well in fact you want to train a regressor, not a classifier.

To train this regressor that simulates a function f: x -> x**2. Your features describe the domain function (real set) and your test set contains the function image. For example :

```
# python3

import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

x = np.arange(0, 101, 2)
y = x**2

rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)
rf.fit(x.reshape(-1,1), y) 
print(rf.predict(5))
```

Output:

```
[ 22.]
```